# Create Dictionary subset from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like the following:

```
d = [{'first':'jason','color':'green','age':22},
     {'first':'josh','color':'red','age':22},
     {'first':'chris','color':'blue','age':21}
    ]
```

I want to create a dictionary that is a subset of the previous dictionaries.

Something that looks like:

```
newD = {'jason':22, 'josh':22, 'chris':21}
```

The following does the trick:

```
first = [k['first'] for k in d]
age = [k['age'] for k in d]
newD = dict(zip(first, age))
```

But is there a more Pythonic/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
newd = {dd['first']: dd['age'] for dd in d}
```

Output:

```
In [3]: newd
Out[3]: {'chris': 21, 'jason': 22, 'josh': 22}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you only need one comprehension:

```
>>> {x['first']: x['age'] for x in d}
{'jason': 22, 'josh': 22, 'chris': 21}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
newD = dict((x['first'], x['age']) for x in d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = dict(map(itemgetter('first', 'age'), d))

{'jason': 22, 'josh': 22, 'chris': 21}
```